# Saxon XQuery and collection : is it possible in FLWOR query to retrieve file names of returned items?

Tags: xquery, saxon

I would like to execute this kind of flwor query (I am using Saxon) :

```
for $baseItem in collection('file:/xmlDir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')/item
  let $itemToRetrieve := xs:string($baseItem/item)
  let $itemFilter := xs:string($baseItem/filter)
  let $fileName := tokenize("*xmlPath($baseItem)*"),'/')[last()]
  where $itemFilter = 'test'
  return ($itemToRetrieve, $fileName)
```

This way I could quickly find, when working on a large collection, where the returned items where found by the processor, without having to use a external program, like find commands.

I have tried to use document-uri() and base-uri() functions but without success.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `document-uri()` function should give you what you want. I just tried

```
collection($someURI)!document-uri(.)
```

and it works for me provided the items in the collection are all document nodes (but it fails with a type error if the collection includes non-XML resources which are retrieved as items other than document nodes)

Another approach is to use uri-collection() which gives you the URIs of the resources rather than the resources themselves; you can then fetch the particular resources you want using the doc() function (or json-doc() or unparsed-text() depending on the type of resource).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tried this :
    `for $uri in collection('file:/xmlDir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')!document-uri(.)
 return ($uri)`

Indeed I obtain the list of the file names.
But now, how can I feed the nodes in the for loop of the flwor query ?
If I try : 

    `for $uri in collection('file:/xmlDir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')!document-uri(.)
 let $item := $uri/item
 return ($item, $uri)`
 
I get the error : "Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyURI"
Maybe the solution is trivial? How can I manage to loop on $items nodes ?

Comment: It's hard to tell you what code to write without knowing what you want to do; I was just demonstrating that you can apply document-uri() to the nodes that come back from collection(), which means you can also do, for example, `for $d in collection(..) return <a uri="{document-uri($d)}">{$d}</a>`

Comment: Thanks. Like in my first exemple, I would like to return from flwor both an item and the file name containing it.
I was able to do that using nested flwor like this :

`for $uri in collection('file:/xmlDir?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')!document-uri(.)
 for $itemToRetrieve in doc(\$uri)/item
   return ($itemToRetrieve, $uri)`
   
But I am afraid I will have to modify a lot of queries, especially when I have to sum values over all the files in the collection.

Is there a way to return the file name without any impact on the original query?

Comment: Please raise a more specific question.

Comment: Ok. Your method with document-uri() works : for all the items returned by the query, it outputs the path of the file containing one specific item. It was my goal so it is OK.
But as I tried to show in my first comment, it forces me to rewrite my queries with two nested loop instead of only one : outer loop on all URIs, inner loop on all items contained in one URI.
The typical query shown in my initial question has only one loop on all the items contained in all documents of the collection.
So I was just wondering if there is a way to avoid such a rewriting of the queries (?).

Comment: Please raise a more specific question, as a new question. I need to know what output you want to produce and what your code looks like that you aren't happy with.